# source and destination path for the copy command in single file then how to copy?

Tags: linux, cp, xargs

I have a single file which contains source file paths and destination file paths.

example

```
$ cat test.txt
/home/data/source.txt   /home/code/destination.txt
/home/abc/def.txt   /home/mnp/xyz.txt
```

Here i want to copy `/home/data/source.txt` to `/home/code/destination.txt` `(cp /home/data/source.txt /home/code/destination.txt`)

I have so many source path and Destination path in a single file

So I want a command by which I can copy file from source path to destination path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

- make a copy of your file: `cp test.txt test.sh`
- put `cp` at the beginning of each line: `sed -i 's/^/cp / test.sh`
- make the file executable: `chmod +x test.sh`
- execute the file: `./test.sh`

Answer (score 1):

```
cat test.txt | xargs -L 1 cp -v
```

where:

- `test.txt` is your input file
- `xargs -L 1` will list lines one by one and run
- `cp` is the `copy` command
- `-v` is there to have visibility and for check